# iOS Notifications Handling

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, push-notification

I know how to handle notifications in terms of how to get the data, but I am trying to figure out how to process that information. When using Facebook app for example, if the application is not in the foreground, and we get the notification, on resume, the user is taken to the view what corresponds to that notification. For example if we get a new message notification, and we tap on it, we go straight to the chat.

So the question is, when I am using storyboards, how can I go straight to the view that would normally require user to navigate through the app a little. Lets say the view we want to go to on notification, requires three pushes of a view controller onto a navigation controller by the user. What would be a good way to do this, is there any way, I don't have to manually call pushViewController or performSegue three times?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513707/navigate-to-a-specific-uiviewcontroller-after-receiving-a-nsnotification